# Is there a better solution for Javascript's order of evaluation?

Tags: javascript, async-await

```
class foo {
  constructor(req) {
    this.req = req;
  }
  async bar() {
    this.req.baz = {};
    return 1;
  }
}
const req = {};
req.baz.boof = await new foo(req).bar();
```

I would have thought that JS would eval the right hand side first and req.baz would be an object before the assignment of req.baz.boof was attempted.  Yet I get an error saying that boof cannot be assigned because req.baz is undefined.  I know the code is terrible and should be refactored.  What fixes it is this:

```
const temp = await new foo(req).bar();
req.baz.boof = temp;
```

Has anyone seen this before?  Is this the best workaround, assuming I can't refactor all the related code?

Comment: *What fixes it is this:* It shouldn't, that'll throw the same error. A `baz` property doesn't exist, so accessing the `boof` property of `baz` throws

Comment: Why would you even do that?

Comment: @epascarello Some people have to maintain legacy code...

Comment: What legacy code used a class? Better solution would be to have a class set the properties.

Comment: Why you would do this is immaterial to the question. If OP had asked this question on Code Review (with a working example), debating why you might do something this way and suggesting alternatives might be better. As OP is specifically providing a contrived but working example it's safe to assume OP wants to know *why* the code is showing this behaviour, not how to do it better.

Comment: I don't think you'd be satisfied with this, but using a promise directly like `new foo(req).bar().then(r => { req.baz.boof = r; })` can be an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation),

> 1. If LeftHandSideExpression is neither an ObjectLiteral nor an ArrayLiteral, then
>    a. Let lref be the result of evaluating LeftHandSideExpression.
>    [...]

I.e. compiler/interpreter needs to evaluate left side first to validate and determine the type for the right side expression.

I can't think of a better fix than proposed in the question.

P.S. It is not a contradiction to the right-to-left rule. RTL means that

```
x = y = 2;
```

is evaluated as

```
x = (y = 2);
```

instead of

```
(x = y) = 2;
```